# SQL BETWEEN prices stored as string

Tags: php, sql, between

I'm running into a problem here. I'm storing prices in my database as a string in the following format: `14.500,00` and `199,95`. Sometime later I created this range slider so the users can filter on price as you can see in the provided image. For this to work, I needed to write a new query so I was thinking of a `BETWEEN` in SQL but this doesn't work on strings. Any ideas to filter on price with a range slider in SQL?

[image]

Comment: Make numbers numbers, not text. If you have a localle that uses dots and commas in a non mathematical way that is the job of the Presentation layer, dont store them in a semi unusable way on the database as text

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on *why* exactly you're storing numerical values as strings?

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer! I will change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BETWEEN` *does* work on strings.  It works just fine -- with the strings ordered alphabetically.

Your problem is that `BETWEEN` on strings doesn't follow the numeric ordering.  Well, that is normal.  If I'm speaking French, I wouldn't expect an English speaker to understand me.  The same with types.  If I use `BETWEEN` on strings, then I expect the comparisons to be *string*-based, not numeric.  (The same is true of dates, by the way.)

Fix your data so the values are stored as `numeric`/`decimal` values.  These are numbers with a fixed number of decimal places, exactly what is needed for monetary values.

In most databases, you will need to get rid of the dollar sign.  Something like this should work:

```
update t
    set price = replace(price, '$', '');

alter table t alter column price numeric(10, 2);  -- or whatever is appropriate
```

The exact syntax might vary, depending on the database.